# Spring Boot how to hide passwords in properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring Boot uses the properties file, and at least by default, the passwords are in plain text. Is it possible to somehow hide/decrypt these?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You can use **Jasypt** to encrypt properties, so you could have your property like this:

```
db.password=ENC(XcBjfjDDjxeyFBoaEPhG14wEzc6Ja+Xx+hNPrJyQT88=)
```

Jasypt allows you to encrypt your properties using different algorithms, once you get the encrypted property you put inside the `ENC(...)`. For instance, you can encrypt this way through Jasypt using the terminal:

```
encrypted-pwd$ java -cp ~/.m2/repository/org/jasypt/jasypt/1.9.2/jasypt-1.9.2.jar  org.jasypt.intf.cli.JasyptPBEStringEncryptionCLI input="contactspassword" password=supersecretz algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES

----ENVIRONMENT-----------------

Runtime: Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 24.45-b08



----ARGUMENTS-------------------

algorithm: PBEWithMD5AndDES
input: contactspassword
password: supersecretz



----OUTPUT----------------------

XcBjfjDDjxeyFBoaEPhG14wEzc6Ja+Xx+hNPrJyQT88=
```

To easily configure it with Spring Boot you can use its starter [jasypt-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/jasypt-spring-boot) with group ID `com.github.ulisesbocchio`

Keep in mind, that you will need to start your application using the same *password* you used to encrypt the properties. So, you can start your app this way:

```
mvn -Djasypt.encryptor.password=supersecretz spring-boot:run
```

Or using the environment variable (thanks to spring boot relaxed binding):

```
export JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=supersecretz
mvn spring-boot:run
```

You can check below link for more details:

https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/spring-boot-password-encryption-with-jasypt/

To use your encrypted properties in your app just use it as usual, use either method you like (Spring Boot wires the magic, anyway the property must be of course in the classpath):

Using `@Value` annotation

```
@Value("${db.password}")
private String password;
```

Or using `Environment`

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

public void doSomething(Environment env) {
    System.out.println(env.getProperty("db.password"));
}
```

Update: for production environment, to avoid exposing the password in the command line, since you can query the processes with `ps`, previous commands with `history`, etc etc. You could:

- Create a script like this: `touch setEnv.sh`
- Edit `setEnv.sh` to export the `JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD` variable

  > #!/bin/bash
  >
  > export JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD=supersecretz
- Execute the file with `. setEnv.sh`
- Run the app in background with `mvn spring-boot:run &`
- Delete the file `setEnv.sh`
- Unset the previous environment variable with: `unset JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD`

Comment: Could you please explain more in details using gradle @Frerica Piazza

Comment: It is not clear about using with maven. you pass some property and what further? Where property file? how to ise this value in code?

Comment: @gstackoverflow, the question is related to encryption/decryption and it's tagged with spring boot, the intention was to explain encryption stuffs not property usage. Anyway, I can edit this answer to give you more details. In the meantime, Spring uses this totally transparent, just inject the propertyes with `@Values("db.password")`. For "where" it is just the classpath. "What further"... nothing, spring boot does all the magic automatically

Comment: I was looking also for a solution to hide my passwords from the properties file and I found the above solution/tool to be very interesting. But, I had once a security issue in a project where passwords were visually exposed on a Linux OS when using the "ps" command (show process list). The whole commandline was displayed in the process list, that is the java commandline including "-DpwdName=pwd" property. Has anyone solved this problem? IBM has a workaround for this issue by letting you define JVM properties in a file and then let the JVM fetch the values without exposing them in the cmdline.

Comment: @user2120188 you can sort out this in different ways, for instance you can create a bash script named `setPass.sh` containing the `export` of your environment variable. So, then you just execute your script. Spring boot allows reading system properties as well as environment variables, and that's all you won't have the password in the shell history

Comment: Passing the password via "mvn -D..." does not work for me ("req. enc. configuration property jasypt.encryptor.pasword missing"). However, setting it in the application.yml works. Any thoughts?

Comment: "mvn spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.arguments=--jasypt.encryptor.password=xxx" works!

Comment: @BigX that is not safe since whoever login in and run the `history` command will see your password

Comment: @FedericoPiazza but this also applies to your very similar command "mvn -Djasypt.encryptor.password=supersecretz spring-boot:run". For security you could run it on a Jenkins e.g. using credentials without exposing the password.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Isn't `mvn -Djasypt.encryptor.password=supersecretz spring-boot:run` going to show up in the `ps` output, exposing the password?

Comment: @SrkiRakic yes, of course. This is just for development, if you want it for production you should use environment variables. Spring boot allows you to use `JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD`

Comment: haha and how does it get into environment variables? Probably from another file like service difinition :D Also jasypt is outdated when it comes to password derivation so make sure to use totally random 32 character password

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Is it possible to encrypt entire YAML and use it in application?

Comment: @AshishBhosle you might be interested in using spring vault for your use case. I would recommend you to create a question with that.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza Thank you for the information. And I have created the a question for the same.

Comment: What is the `input=` parameter used for on the `jar ...` command line to generate the encryption key? Can it be anything, or does it reference some kind of variable?

Comment: @ChrisF as shown in my answer `input` is the text that you want to encrypt. You can use whatever text you want.

Comment: @FedericoPiazza, I thought `supersecretz` is the p/w you wanted to encrypt. Or is that the p/w to be used by the application to decrypt the encrypted p/w?

Comment: @ChrisF I think you are misunderstanding how the encryption works. The `input="this is the text I want to encrypt"` and `password="this is the key used to encrypt the input"`

Comment: Be aware that the last commit to jasypt happened almost two years ago. There is also an open issue with a lot of critique about the encryption algorithms here: https://github.com/jasypt/jasypt/issues/31

Comment: your url is a dead url

Comment: @pixel I've updated the url, check again

Comment: @FedericoPiazza  Thanks, I will take a look.  But interestingly, I was able to get it working for the application; however, all my tests are failing with `Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: either 'jasypt.encryptor.password', one of ['jasypt.encryptor.private-key-string', 'jasypt.encryptor.private-key-location'] for asymmetric encryption, or one of ['jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-string', 'jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-location', 'jasypt.encryptor.gcm-secret-key-password'] for AES/GCM encryption must be provided for ...`

Comment: jasypt hasn't been updated for years, I would refrain from adding it to a project

Answer (score 23):

To the already proposed solutions I can add an option to configure an external `Secrets Manager` such as [Vault](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/#getting-started).

1. Configure Vault Server `vault server -dev` (**Only for DEV and not for PROD**)
2. Write secrets `vault write secret/somename key1=value1 key2=value2`
3. Verify secrets `vault read secret/somename`

Add the following dependency to your SpringBoot project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-vault-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add Vault config properties:

```
spring.cloud.vault.host=localhost
spring.cloud.vault.port=8200
spring.cloud.vault.scheme=http
spring.cloud.vault.authentication=token
spring.cloud.vault.token=${VAULT_TOKEN}
```

Pass `VAULT_TOKEN` as an environment variable.

Refer to the documentation [here.](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/single/spring-cloud-vault.html)

There is a [Spring Vault](https://projects.spring.io/spring-vault) project which is also can be used for accessing, storing and revoking secrets.

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.vault</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-vault-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Configuring Vault Template:

```
@Configuration
class VaultConfiguration extends AbstractVaultConfiguration {

  @Override
  public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {
    return new VaultEndpoint();
  }

  @Override
  public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {
    return new TokenAuthentication("…");
  }
}
```

Inject and use VaultTemplate:

```
public class Example {

  @Autowired
  private VaultOperations operations;

  public void writeSecrets(String userId, String password) {
      Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
      data.put("password", password);
      operations.write(userId, data);
  }

  public Person readSecrets(String userId) {
      VaultResponseSupport<Person> response = operations.read(userId, Person.class);
      return response.getBody();
  }
}
```

Use Vault `PropertySource`:

```
@VaultPropertySource(value = "aws/creds/s3",
  propertyNamePrefix = "aws."
  renewal = Renewal.RENEW)
public class Config {

}
```

Usage example:

```
public class S3Client {

  // inject the actual values
  @Value("${aws.access_key}")
  private String awsAccessKey;
  @Value("${aws.secret_key}")
  private String awsSecretKey;

  public InputStream getFileFromS3(String filenname) {
    // …
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for this solution. Using a system like vault / etcd (or any other) is the way to go. https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/

Comment: -1 because this doesn't explain how the "master" key (VAULT_TOKEN) is secured. Where did the VAULT_TOKEN environment variable come from? How is it secured? Without protecting that key, the attacker can use it to retrieve the secrets from the vault using the code packaged in the Spring Boot jar.

Comment: Also securing prod is the main issue. So, it has to be spoken here. Guidance for Dev/QA environments if fine.

Comment: This works when there are many passwords. It works for one password to connect but its funny to say put the vault password in the environment so you don't have to put the other password in the same environment.

Comment: why we want to use just for dev? prod is important.

Answer (score 20):

**UPDATE:** I noticed folks down-voting this, so I have to say that although this is not an ideal solution, but this works and acceptable in some use-cases.
Cloudfoundry uses Environment variables to inject credentials when a Service is binded to an application. More info https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html

And also if your system is not shared, then for local development this is also acceptable. Of course, the more safe and secure way is explained in [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54145503/5702727) by @J-Alex.

**Answer:**

If you want to hide your passwords then the easiest solution is to use **Environment variables** in `application.properties` file or directly in your code.

In `application.properties`:

```
mypassword=${password}
```

Then in your configuration class:

```
@Autowired
private Environment environment;

[...]//Inside a method
System.out.println(environment.getProperty("mypassword"));
```

In your `configuration` class:

```
@Value("${password}")
private String herokuPath;

[...]//Inside a method
System.out.println(herokuPath);
```

**Note:** You might have to restart after setting the environment variable. 
For windows:

[image: In Windows]

Refer this [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) for more info.

Comment: I do not think setting the master password in the environment vars is such a good idea. The password is now more exposed than necessary. 
Providing it a startup as shown by Federico is less exposed and more "secure" than setting it in the environment.

Comment: Yaa, its not if you are using shared computer. But if you are the only administrator of your computer then no other user can see the env vars. I answered the hiding part and the easier one. But yes, I agree Federico's suggested method is way better.

Comment: Please see: https://diogomonica.com/2017/03/27/why-you-shouldnt-use-env-variables-for-secret-data/

Comment: @Jaavaaan providing JASYPT_ENCRYPTOR_PASSWORD in environment variable to decode db password is equally insecure as this answer.

Comment: @Jaavaaan Please read the *Update*. I've already mentioned that this isn't secure in all cases, but there are valid use-cases like CF. Also pointed to a better highly secure solution of using HashiCorp Vault.

Comment: Is running the spring boot application environment variables are safe?

Answer (score 13):

Spring Cloud Config Server will allow this type of behavior.  Using JCE you can setup a key on the server and use it to cipher the apps properties.

http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html

Comment: Could you please share more details ?

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using quite popular in Spring Boot environment Kubernetes (K8S) or OpenShift, there's a possibility to store and retrieve application properties on runtime. This technique called *secrets*. In your configuration yaml file for Kubernetes or OpenShift you declare variable and placeholder for it, and on K8S\OpenShift side declare actual value which corresponds to this placeholder.
For implementation details, see:
K8S: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
OpenShift: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/secrets.html

Answer (score 1):

In additional to the popular K8s, jasypt or vault solutions, there's also [Karmahostage](https://karmahostage.com/spring-boot-encryption?ref=stackoverflow). It enables you to do:

```
@EncryptedValue("${application.secret}")
private String application;
```

It works the same way jasypt does, but encryption happens on a dedicated saas solution, with a more fine-grained ACL model attached to it.

Answer (score -1):

My solution for hiding a DB-Password in Spring Boot apps [application.properties](https://github.com/senatov/spring-boot-primerfaces-sheduler/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties) is implemented [here](https://github.com/senatov/spring-boot-primerfaces-sheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/de/senatov/reservatio/utl/SchedUtilility.java).

Scenario: some fake password is read from [application.properties](https://github.com/senatov/spring-boot-primerfaces-sheduler/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties) on start and saved in global Spring object ConfigurableEnvironment. In runtime it will be programmatically replaced with a real DB password.
The real password will be read from another config file saved in a safe, project-external place.

Don't forget: call the the [Bean](https://github.com/senatov/spring-boot-primerfaces-sheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/de/senatov/reservatio/utl/SchedUtilility.java) from [main class](https://github.com/senatov/spring-boot-primerfaces-sheduler/blob/master/src/main/java/de/senatov/reservatio/SpringBootAppMain.java) with:

```
@Autowired
private SchedUtilility utl;
```