# How to store application.properites values using manifest.yml to contain passwords?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

So my application.properties would look like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=123456
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
```

I don't want others to be able to see my user and password when they go into my application.properties file.

Is there an alternative way to push values to cloud foundry? Something like manifest.yml?

**Attempt to create manifest.yml**

I tried to make a manifest file so I can bind it with my application on cloud foundry.

```
VCAP_SERVICES =
{
  "oraclesql": [
    {
      "name": "OrcaleDb",
      "label": "oraclesql",
      "tags": [
        "oracledb",
        "oracle",
        "relational"
      ],
      "plan": "free",
      "credentials": {
        "uri": "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb",
        "username": "user",
        "password": "123456"        
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Created application.yml**

```
//this works
    spring:
        application:
            name: tester
        datasource:
            driverClassName: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=mydb
            username: user
            password: 123456
            initialize: false
        jpa:
            databasePlatform: org.hiberate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot how to hide passwords in properties file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file)

Comment: If you just want them out of application.properties, take a look at the docs on externalizing configuration for Spring Boot -> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html.  An option that works well with CF is to set environment variables.  You can set them through manifest.yml too.

Comment: Can you provide me a link on how to set them through manifest.yml? @DanielMikusa That is what I want to do. Switch from app.properties to manifest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.  Unfortunately the `manifest.yml` doesn't work quite like that.  The file provides the settings that will be used for `cf push`.  It's application agnostic and doesn't know anything about Spring, Java, your programming language or your application framework of choice.  Thus it cannot make changes to your application.properties file or other framework specific configuration.

Fortunately, there are many ways to configure Spring Boot (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)) and one of them is via environment variables.  What's fortunate about this is that you can set environment variables via `manifest.yml`.  Thus if you set the proper environment variables in `manifest.yml`, you can configure your application.

For reference, here are instructions for setting env variables in `manifest.yml`.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/manifest.html#env-block

It looks roughly like this:

```
---
  ...
  env:
    ENV_1: val_1
    ENV_2: val_2
```

Spring Boot will map environment variables to properties using the rules explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).  A basic example would be `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` maps to `spring.datasource.username` in application.properties.

Comment: With manifest.yml my password would be hardcoded as a ENV and the value will be passed into application.properies, Correct?

Comment: Yes.  It's not passed in though, so much as it overrides what's set in application.properties.  If you have ENV_1 env variable, it will override env.1 in the properties file.  Look at Spring Boot docs (link in my post) for order of these overrides.

Comment: How would I be able to rewrite this as a manifest.yml VCap services? I posted my attempt it dont seem to work.

Comment: That's a different question altogether.  What you're asking now is how to pull credentials from a bound service.  There's a lot of ways to do this in Spring.  Some are covered here:  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/java/spring-service-bindings.html.  I also found this blog to be very helpful, it explains the different options well: https://spring.io/blog/2015/04/27/binding-to-data-services-with-spring-boot-in-cloud-foundry

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do here is have your database connection as a cloud foundry [service](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/) rather than defined in your `application.properties`.  As Daniel's answer suggests, Spring can pick up ENV variables, but setting connection details in the manifest is not the idiomatic way to do this.

By having a service, the connection details are stored in the `VCAP_SERVICES` variable when bound to the application - spring can read from there.  The [spring-music](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-samples/spring-music) app shows the prototypical way of doing this.