# Securing a Spring boot api rest service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a spring boot api secured with spring basic security. I call the api from another application. So I currently have the password in plain text in the application.yml files of my api and also the application.yml file from which I am calling the service.

How can I avoid having it in plain text in the yml? is there a way to have an encrypted password in both yml files?

Comment: Maybe a vault solution is what you are looking for: http://projects.spring.io/spring-vault/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Jasypt (Java Simplified Encryption). [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file) was very helpful