# How I can encrypt/decrypt Spring boot server properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption

I have a spring boot application that uses SSL. In my properties file I defined a value for my keystore password ,the idea is to not expose the password in the clear  so I encrypted the password and i'm looking in spring boot how i can decrypt this password value :

```
server.port=8443
server.ssl.key-alias=selfsigned_certif
server.ssl.key-password=JDHF7E879E7R79E7D9D7Fkdskjdhdkjsdghjsfdghsgfd
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:ssl-server.jks
server.ssl.key-store-provider=SUN
server.ssl.key-store-type=JKS
```

In my case I can't use **Jasypt** because of we should use a specific developped library for encrypt and decrypt the password

Is there a way to implement encryption/ decryption of keystore properties using Spring boot ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered putting sensitive configuration in a vault?

Comment: In my case I can't use Jasypt because of we should use a specific developped library for encrypt and decrypt the password

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for spring boot related answer I suggest taking a look at [spring-cloud-config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/single/spring-cloud-config.html) project.

This project allows managing configurations externally (in filesystem or in git, for example), and among other things has a support for encrypting property values both via symmetric private secret and via public/private key pair

A "protected" Property, in this case, looks like this:

```
db.password={cipher}AZXCASDAZXC341234ZXCASDFedr453
```

Where the AZXCASDAZXC341234ZXCASDFedr453 is actually an encrypted value of some password.
In order to encrypt it, you should call the "encrypt" method one time, assuming the spring-cloud-config server is running on port 8888 of your machine.

```
 $ curl localhost:8888/encrypt -d mysecretdbpassword >>AZXCASDAZXC341234ZXCASDFedr453
```

Here the value of password "mysecretdbopassword" gets encrypted.

The key has to be specified in configurations of the spring-cloud-config microservice itself.

```
 encrypt.key=ABC123ABC123ABC123
```

Another option that this service has is an integration with Hashicorp vault, so it also can be a good candidate for keeping the secrets.

Comment: In my case I can't use Jasypt because of we should use a specific developped library for encrypt and decrypt the password

Comment: In this case you can just borrow the idea: create an "encrypted" value offline, and put some prefix to the property so that the decryption that will happen in runtime will know which properties should be decrypted and which shouldn't. You can check the source code of spring-cloud-config and implement it there, or roll your own properties loader.

Comment: I used this library to encrytp and decrypt value in my properties files the problem was with the spring boot keys server.ssl.key-password for example this value i could not get it in code using @Value

Comment: What if I need to decrypt it at server startup using maven ? Can't create bean 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer'.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**  There is a similar/better answer to a duplicate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file), as pointed out by [Adam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464657/adam) in his comment.

---

We did something similar by incorporating the [Jasypt](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jasypt) tool.  It's nicely baked into the Spring eco-system.  Basically you encrypt the values with an encryption key (a string) and put the encrypted value in your properties file surrounded by `ENC(...)`.  Then you put the encryption key in a specified environment variable on the server where your code is running.  You can then map the encrypted values directly into variables with `@Value(...)`.

Another option is not to store the password in your source at all, and instead secure those on the server in environment variables and access them directly at runtime.  I think any way you slice it you end up relying on the fact that the server is secure, so it's important that you are confident that your server won't be compromised.

Comment: In my case I can't use Jasypt because of we should use a specific developped library for encrypt and decrypt the password