# Encrypt passwords in a WebApp

Tags: servlets, encryption, password-encryption

I'm developing a WebApp using JavaEE (Servlets + JSP).

I have found a problem when I want to write some passwords in my app, like a SMTP password. While I'm debugging I have write it in plain, inside the code or in properties file, but I would like to encrypt them somehow.

What I do in developing stage:

```
private static final String SMTP_PASS = "my_pass";
```

How could I do that? Any ideas/examples?

Comment: Encrypting the password just kicks the can; now you have to protect the encryption key instead of the password. What are you trying to protect from? Does encryption really solve that problem?

Comment: A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57168781/how-to-hide-the-password-in-the-command-java-djasypt-encryptor-password-somepa) has some suggestions.  But to the point @Peter makes it just moves the problem somewhat.  Services like AWS have better ways of managing this but at the end of the day you need that clear text password.

Comment: @Peter the thing is... I have to put anywhere my SMTP password, so, where is the best place to write it down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static final String SMTP_PASS = "my_pass_identifier"; //here my_pass_identifier is not the actual password its just an identifier to identify the SMTP password
```

Create a properties file for storing passwords in encrypted form in key/val pairs. Note you can encrypt the password using EncryptDecrypt class mentioned below and pass the encrypted password in the properties file

```
SMTP_PASS = nPDHgg/DYzcL2+HsvYZruw==javaxMQyYxBZUsf7c0gh+vkisQA==javax0w+9tvuLzY04TA5FyTVSPw==
```

Create a class CredentialUtilities which will decrypt the password by reading the password.properties file

```
public class CredentialUtilities {
    static PasswordEncrypt pe = new PasswordEncrypt();
    public static String  getCredentials(String identifier) throws Exception{

        String credential = "";
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        InputStream input = null;

        try {
           String filename = "password.properties";
            input = CredentialUtilities.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
            prop.load(input);
            String property = prop.getProperty(identifier);
            credential = pe.decrypt(property); 
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally{
            if(input!=null){
                try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
        }
        return credential;

    }
}
```

Create a class that will Encrypt/Decrypt you password for you

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class EncryptDecrypt {
    public static String ALGORITHM = "AES";
    private static String AES_CBS_PADDING = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
    private static int AES_128 = 128;


    private static byte[] encryptDecrypt(final int mode, final byte[] key, final byte[] IV, final byte[] message)
            throws Exception {
        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_CBS_PADDING);
        final SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, ALGORITHM);
        final IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(IV);
        cipher.init(mode, keySpec, ivSpec);
        return cipher.doFinal(message);
    }

    public static Map<String, SecretKey> keyGenerator() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException{
        Map<String, SecretKey> map = new HashMap<String, SecretKey>();
         KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(EncryptDecrypt.ALGORITHM);
         keyGenerator.init(AES_128);
         SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
         map.put("key", key);
         SecretKey IV = keyGenerator.generateKey();
         map.put("iv", IV);
         return map;

    }


    public static String encrypt(String message) throws Exception{
        Map<String , SecretKey> map = keyGenerator();
        SecretKey key = map.get("key");
        SecretKey IV = map.get("iv");
        byte[] cipherText = encryptDecrypt(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key.getEncoded(), IV.getEncoded(), message.getBytes());
        String encrypted_message =  Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipherText);
        String encodedKey = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(map.get("key").getEncoded());
        String encodedIV = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(map.get("iv").getEncoded());

        return encrypted_message+"javax"+encodedIV+"javax"+encodedKey;



    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) throws Exception{
        String[] result = encryptedMessage.split("javax");
        byte[] decodedIV = Base64.getDecoder().decode(result[1]);
        byte[] decodedKey = Base64.getDecoder().decode(result[2]);
        byte[] cipher_text = Base64.getDecoder().decode(result[0]);
        SecretKey IV = new SecretKeySpec(decodedIV, 0, decodedIV.length, "AES");
        SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, 0, decodedKey.length, "AES");    
        byte[] decryptedString = encryptDecrypt(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key.getEncoded(), IV.getEncoded(), cipher_text);
        String decryptedMessage = new String(decryptedString);
        return decryptedMessage;

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EncryptDecrypt cu = new EncryptDecrypt();
        String encryptedmessage =  cu.encrypt("usrpswd");
        System.out.println(encryptedmessage);
        String decryptedMessage = cu.decrypt(encryptedmessage);
        System.out.println(decryptedMessage);
    }

}
```

You can now get the decrypted password whereever you want using.

```
String SMTP_PASSWORD = new CredentialUtilities().getCredentials(SMTP_PASS);
```

Comment: Rajendra Gupta, do you know how to increase the security to that algorithm? it's 128bit and it throws me error if I modify the quantity.