# How to encrypt the user/pw and ftp connection in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, ftp

So I have a working ftp connection and I can upload files and whatnot. However currently I'm storing the pw/user as hardcoded values (which I know isn't good) and want to see if I can hide/encrypt them somehow. I would also like to encrypt the actual ftp connection if possible as well. Any information/pointers would be great!

```java
private int ftpProcess(String serverName, String userName, String password) {
    FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    int statusCode = 0;
    try {
        ftp.connect(serverName);
        // was required to add this passive mode in TC8 to connect to the mainframe
        ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        ftp.login(userName, password);

        ftp.site("filetype=jes");

        submitJcl(ftp, "submitTest.txt", serverName);

        ftp.quit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        statusCode = 3;
    }
    return statusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can encrypt values in your application.properties with Jasypt.

See the following link for a details description:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37424296/13454816

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Spring, you could can add `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security` dependency and use BCryptPasswordEncoder to encode the values:

```
BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
String enc = encoder.encode(value);
```

Documentation is here:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html

And this is a very helpful tutorial:

- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt