# How to encrypt HSQLDB User Password using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hsqldb

I have an Spring Boot based application and a external HSQLDB folder that contains

- db.data
- db.properties
- db.script

My application load & connect to this db, everything  is fine. The problem is, that the username and passwword are written in db.script file as plain text.

How I can encrypt this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot how to hide passwords in properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file)

Comment: He does not want to encrypt the password in the `application.properties` but in the datsbase filed @Issam EL-ATIF

Comment: @IssamEL-ATIF No, as I understand in that post he use a memory db with config data in his application.properties.  My configuration is in db.script file.  Its an external db file. Is it possble to create a user programmatically  with Beans?

Comment: @Tristate Sorry i thought it was in db.properties

Comment: Are you using HSQLDB 1.8? In the latest versions of HSQLDB 2.5.x there is only a password hash in the .script file.