# How to hide database credentials in Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, mysql, linux, spring-boot, information-hiding

### SOLVED

---

### Solution:

Using **Jasypt**. You can click [here](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/spring-boot-password-encryption) for more information how to set up. There is just **one** thing to mention. For me, it didn't work as if I configure the *application.properties* as they say. Therefore, you have to add one more line. These are the steps how to encrypt your credentials and configure them in application.properties:

1. First you need to encrypt the string values running this in your terminal (**NOTE:** I am currently using Linux, so it may vary depending on your OS):

```
mvn jasypt:encrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password=encryptorPassword -Djasypt.plugin.value=password
```

After running this you would see something like this:

```
ENC(MBTWfX8gqMevQe5CKW0pToMbajnpJk0zlb3yoooiSWPjkfYrE8TFNF6vDEMXTu/j)
```

This is going to be your encrypted value wrapped inside ENC().

You can then check if your *password* is actually encrypted. Run this command:

```
mvn jasypt:decrypt-value -Djasypt.encryptor.password=encryptorPassword -Djasypt.plugin.value=MBTWfX8gqMevQe5CKW0pToMbajnpJk0zlb3yoooiSWPjkfYrE8TFNF6vDEMXTu/j
```

And you should see your actual *password*.
Following the same steps, you can encrypt your database name etc. as well.

2. Now, you have to pass **VM** argument in your IDE, I am going to show you how to do in in **IntelliJ**. Go to `Edit Configurations` in the IDE and fill `Program arguments`, therefore `apply` then `OK` button:
   [image]
3. Last step is to correctly set up configuration file, here I am showing how to configure it in **application.properties** file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?serverTimezone=UTC&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=ENC(MBTWfX8gqMevQe5CKW0pToMbajnpJk0zlb3yoooiSWPjkfYrE8TFNF6vDEMXTu/j)
jasypt.encryptor.password=encryptorPassword
jasypt.encryptor.algorithm=PBEWithMD5AndDES
jasypt.encryptor.iv-generator-classname=org.jasypt.iv.NoIvGenerator
```

Now, your Spring Boot Application should just work fine. Good Luck!

---

I am currently using the latest version of Spring Boot(version 3.0.5) in **IntelliJ IDEA**. I want to hide my database credentials, *username* and *password*, in a good way then configure them in the **application.properties**.

**Note:** I am using Linux(Ubuntu) and you can assume that my credentials are correct.

As far as I know, a good way of handling this problem is setting up environment variables and configure them in the **application.properties** or whatever you are using to store your configuration properties.
Therefore, in the **./zhsrc** file I set new environment variables: `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD`. After, I configured them in the **.properties** file. Here how it looks like:
[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJM9E.png).

However, it is like my environment variables are not recognized during the application running. I get this error:

```
2023-04-23 10:42:14 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
...
...
2023-04-23 10:42:14 [main] WARN  o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user '${DB_USERNAME}'@'localhost' (using password: YES
```

I solved this problem using alternative way (I don't like it though). What I did is creating two script files (in the source root) named `run_app.sh`(this sets up the same environment variables temporarily every time during running the script) and `stop_app.sh`(this kills the process running on the *8080* port). If I don't have `stop_app.sh`, I can't run the application again, as it cannot be run on the same port. It was the way of killing the process on the *8080* port. 
Why I don't want to run these scripts is that, if I want to write some tests I will face the same issue, then I have to create other scripts, specifically for my tests.
*AGREE...Boring and long*

How would you handle this problem?

Comment: Different suggestions to hide credentials in your SpringBoot application are use Jasypt to encrypt properties or configure an external Secrets Manager like HashiCorp Vault. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file

Comment: Thank you this helped, everything is fine now :)