# Is there way to encrypt ldap password in spring boot application ? (at least base64)

Tags: java, spring-boot, base64, unboundid-ldap-sdk

In my spring boot application I have following configuration for LDAP

```
ldap:
  connection:
    host: 123.45.67.89
    port: 389
    user: CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=MYCOMPANY,DC=COM
    password: SuPeRsEcrEt123#
```

Is there way to encrypt LDAP password ? at least Base64

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot how to hide passwords in properties file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file)

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37404703/spring-boot-how-to-hide-passwords-in-properties-file

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Cloud Config to do this.

1. Include the `spring-cloud-starter-config` dependency.
2. Install the Spring Boot CLI and add the Cloud CLI to it. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/cli.html) and [this](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-cli/reference/html/).
3. Encrypt your password by issuing the `spring encrypt <string to encrypt> --key <encrypt key>`.
4. Replace the password in your properties file with the encrypted password and preface the password with '{cipher}'. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/reference/server/encryption-and-decryption.html).
5. Start your application with `-DENCRYPT_KEY=<encrypt key>` or `-Dencrypt.key=<encrypt key>`.

Comment: Will it work with ordinary spring boot app(not spring cloud) ?

Comment: Yes, it will work in a Spring Boot app.